# References into the tables in different style of the text

Tags: bibliographies, floats, formatting, citing, superscripts

I would like to do one question concerning to references into the tables. So, I am writing my Phd thesis and I have so many tables with theoretical and experimental values. For the experimental values I have references to add, but I would like to add these references like superscript. However in the text the references are into the brackets like, for example [25];[10]... is possible to change just into the table? I have used, for example, `\cite{Edgar1994}` into the tabel and the result was the experimental value plus the reference such as 1.94[25]. I would like [25] superscript without brackets and link to the bibliography.

---

I am using `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` and `bibtex` to create my bibliography.

Comment: What are you using to create your bibliography? bibtex? biblatex? Which style are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I created an example and mentioned that your bibliography style doesn't have a numeric style.

The redefinition of a command like `\cite` isn't the best practice. Instead you should define your own command. In the following example I provided the command `\scite`. The declaration is done with the help of the package [`\cite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{cite,xspace}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@citess[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\scite}{%
    \@ifnextchar[{\@tempswatrue\@citex}{\@tempswafalse\@citew}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{whole-collection}
\cite{unpublished-full}

Text \scite{whole-collection}

Text \scite{unpublished-full}


\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```